# Mega-High Rep, 1 Question

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm curious. I figure that I must be doing something wrong, because I am seeing many, many people with staggeringly high SO reps, and when I view their profile, I see that they have asked a total of 1 (one) question in their entire tenure here.

As someone who spews out questions like a manky router in promiscuous mode, this seems quite strange to me.

Are we somehow penalized for asking questions?

Is there some kind of bias against asking questions?

I'm absolutely serious. I am not actually that interested in obtaining a high SO rank, as it comes with responsibilities (and I tend to honor responsibilities), but it has been galling to have someone tell me that my question is bad, then I go to their profile, and I see that they have only ever asked one question, and they are a very senior member of this site.

Comment: Other way around: You don't get penalized for asking questions (unless of course if the question sucks). Instead, it's the answers that are rewarded more.

Comment: That's interesting, as I suspect the lion's share of my SO points have been from people upvoting the questions, and my answers (which are often very good ones -polishes fingernails on lapel) seldom get any votes at all, usually because I tend to answer not-so-fresh questions.

Comment: I don't have staggeringly high rep, but if you look at my profile, you'll see just one question. One reason for this is that I search and research to hell and back before I even *consider* posting a question. And usually I find my answer without having to post a question. So I tend to post answers, not questions. I can imagine I'm not alone in this.

Comment: @MAGSHARE For a long time, hardly anyone ever voted on questions, and votes were very disproportionately awarded to answers (that's the reason it doesn't cost the voter -1 to downvote questions anymore).  But the high-rep users are often very skilled developers and skilled communicators. We take pleasure in answering and just may not that often have questions of our own to ask.

Comment: I have asked just a handful of questions in my career. However, I have _started_ to ask many more, but as @Louis alluded, I discovered the answer in the process of asking. It's a form of [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Got it, but one of the reasons that I ask here, is that I am usually working on a schedule, and if I can find the answer in a timely fashion, I do. I can usually find the answer to an issue, but it may not be "timely." My workflow here, is first I do my best to find the answer on my own, then I Google it, which usually ends up giving me SO questions, then I see if any of them are relevant, then, if not, I start typing in a question, and see if answers pop up. If not, I post the question. I'm not especially worried about what y'all think of me. I'm good at this gig, but I can always do better.

Comment: Different people participate in SO for different reasons. I am retired, but happen to like answering technical questions as a hobby. If I have a question of my own, I can afford to spend a week researching and experimenting, so I usually find an answer myself. That results in hundreds of answers and a couple of questions.

Comment: Don't be like a manky router in promiscuous mode, sparky.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for [this](http://statestreetgang.net/2013/06/21/the-ten-commandments-of-development/), BTW. Also BTW: I was being a bit snarky. It may seem that way to folks that have asked a total of one question in their tenure here, but I am CONSTANTLY pushing the limits, and you can't help but generate questions when you are into something new every other day.

Answer (score 20):

> As someone who spews out questions like a manky router in promiscuous mode, this seems quite strange to me.

I don't know why you'd find it strange to see high-rep users with low numbers of questions. Stack Overflow rewards both questions and answers, and people with lots of answers (implying a larger body of knowledge and experience) naturally have fewer questions.

> Is there some kind of bias against asking questions?

Absolutely not, but there's a bias against bad questions, and we have very well formed opinions on what constitutes good questions.

> ...  but it has been galling to have someone tell me that my question is bad, then I go to their profile, and I see that they have only ever asked one question, and they are a very senior member of this site.

Why? Most food critics aren't cooks. Most movie reviewers have never made a movie. Most people have opinions on music but will never record a song.

Some senior members may have asked few questions, but they've probably read *thousands*. You don't have to write questions to know what makes a question easy to *read*. Indeed, writing a lot of questions gives you almost *no* insight into what makes a good question for the people writing *answers*.

The bigger problem, by far, is that it's too easy for people to ask hundreds of questions without ever reading anybody else's questions. We have many users who ask huge numbers of questions which are universally of mediocre quality. These people aren't interested in the site or other people's contributions, they just want answers.

On a personal note, I've asked 12 questions in 5 years, but I've posted over 2000 answers, visited the site on 1600 days, read *who knows* how many thousands of questions and made 6700 edits. I'm pretty sure I can tell a good question from a bad question.

Comment: Hmm... it's fairly clear that folks that ask many questions are considered lazy/bad programmers. I have asked questions that I have solved on my own, or that had an obvious answer that I overlooked (happens to the best of us), but I have had many answers here, as well. I'll continue to ask, but I am disappointed that y'all think I'm bad/lazy, because of this (you can rest assured that I'm smart enough not to think this of you). I can point to a pretty massive body of heterogenous FOSS code I've written, that says otherwise.

Comment: @MAGSHARE: Actually, reading it all, I don't get the impression that the commenters think you are a lazy git for asking questions. Also, you seem to ask ok quesstions after doing reasonable research, so you are welcome here (You might sometimes include a slight bit too much fluff, partly self-deprecating, but that stays at most minor). So, keep it up (especially the learning-part). (I'm certainly not an expert on asking questions myself, though ;-))

Comment: Thanks. I really like this place. My questions often result in high-quality answers within minutes. That's a HUGE deal. As a manager, I would value someone who asks a question, and gets high-value input in a few minutes over someone who insists on finding their own answer at the cost of hours of trial and error; often resulting in shaky, "witch doctor" results. I guess that SO is a bit of a victim of its own success.

Comment: @MAGSHARE I'm sorry you took away that we think you're lazy. I don't, at all. People have to ask questions for this site to survive and thrive, we appreciate people who ask lots of *good* questions very much. I personally think people who ask as lot of *bad* questions are lazy. Everybody has moments when they overlook the obvious, but if you're the sort of person asking a question every hour, consistently getting dragged through huge comment threads asking for clarification, getting a lot of down or close votes, that's an indication that your questions might not be as good as they could be.

Comment: I'm not. I think that it's interesting that it was automatically assumed that I am that type of person. I'm a senior development manager of a C++ shop, with over 30 years of experience. I write a lot of code to keep my chops up. I have seen a great deal of discussion, recently, about how to reduce the number of "bad" questions, but "bad" is in the eye of the beholder. If you guys have problems with "bad" questions, then lead from the front. Ask "good" questions, so we can see how it's done. Don't just insult us. Help us to ask better questions.

Comment: @MAGSHARE Regarding your previous comment, I *am* a technical manager. I hire people and manage a team of developers. I look for people who can solve problems well, regardless of how you get it done. But if the only tool in your bag of tricks is to ask for the answer on Stack Overflow, there is a huge problem. You shouldn't be asking for the answer to trivial problems. I don't want devs who aren't curious enough to at least experiment their way through the small stuff. If it produces "witch doctor" code, that's *good*. We catch it in code-review and everybody learns.

Comment: @MAGSHARE I'm not going to artificially invent questions to ask just to "lead the way", and I don't have to. There are tons of good questions posted all the time. There are [7 million](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano) mostly good questions in the site. As with *all things* everywhere on the entire Internet, **lurk more**. The good questions are already there. The onus is on you to look at the site you're contributing to and try to make sure you contributions are on par.

Comment: @MAGSHARE Lastly, again, I didn't assume you where "that type of person", and I don't think anybody else did. You asked why some people feel entitled to critique your questions despite having asked very few, and I offered an explanation, and part of that explanation is that *asking* lots of questions doesn't necessarily make you good at it. That's all. If somebody critiqued a question of yours, it was because of the *question*, not because of assumptions made about you.

Comment: I do lurk a lot. I've been a member here for a couple of years. In that time, I've probably written a couple 100KLoC, and asked 30-some questions. That's not a whole lot of questions for a lot of code. I find most of my answers on my own, or from other sources. That said, SO could definitely be a single tool. There's some seriously good stuff here, and folks can learn a great deal from this place. You don't have to "make up" questions. Anybody that is seriously working on code will be constantly running into issues. Some of these could definitely turn into questions, even if only rhetorical.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. My last question was two years ago. In the last 6 months I've contributed 40,000 lines of code to my primary project alone. Writing code is a big part of my life, I just don't have questions which aren't answered through a modicum of research.

Comment: Then you guys are definitely much better coders than I am. Glad to be amongst such august company. I'll keep asking my silly questions, and we'll all be happy. Thanks!